# Issue with global variables in my node js project

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am experiencing an issue with global variables in my NodeJs project. In this project, I have implemented webservices with express module. When client consumes the service, json object is sent in the request body. I am reading all the properties in the request body and putting in the global variables (as show below).

```
if(obj.businessEntities.year != null || obj.businessEntities.year=='undefined')    
      GLOBAL.gEffectiveYear = obj.businessEntities.year;
```

My issue with above Global variable is, value of first request is used for the next request if year is not passed in the json (it is working just like static variables in java). I want to make this thread-safe or maintain the values unique for each request. is there any other alternative than using global variables? Please help.

My reason to use global variables is, I wanted to set values of json object once, and use the values across all js files.

Comment: Then... don't use a global variable....

Comment: @MadaraUchiha thanks for your suggestion, I am asking if there is any other alternative to global variables to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Whoops, my first answer missed the last line of your question, and thought you were talking about session globals. Here's an edit:*

What you actually want to do is to expose the variable in a ***module*** and ***require*** them from your other files.  See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html for details and syntax.